# What should I do when my ets forecast residuals are correlated?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, residuals, exponential-smoothing

I am currently forecasting seasonally un-adjusted GDP and ran into an issue with residuals where there is a very large negative residual around the financial crises of 07/08. As this is homework I cannot show which country I am forecasting GDP for, but I will try to explain as best I can.

I am using ETS models using the ets() function in R, and after trying every combination of Errors, trend, and seasonality 'ZZZ', I picked the model that resulted in the lowest AICc, which for this dataset was multiplicative errors, additive trend and multiplicative seasonality.

The errors have a mean = 0.0002, which is practically 0.
However, the residuals are correlated (autocorrelation) with a Ljung-Box test p-value of 0.0003. The residual plot takes a dramatic downturn at around the start of the financial crisis. This means that I can improve the ETS model right? In which case, what are some general steps that I can use to improve my ETS forecast?

Comment: One of Scott Armstrong’s forecasting rules of thumb:
If you have data that is generally trended,
But there is a trend break. (as there is during the financial crisis, so you have a string of residuals in the same direction)
Until that trend comes back use a naïve forecast.
You don’t know how long the trend break will last.  (Unfortunately, that's a practical rule of thumb and might not be useful for homework.)